# Can't use Enum value as data of type Enum["A"] | Enum["B"] | etc

Tags: typescript, enums, interface

```
export enum ChartType {
  Table = 'Table',
  Pie = 'Pie',
  DonutPie = 'DonutPie',
  Column = 'Column',
  Bar = 'Bar',
  Line = 'Line',
  StackedBar = 'StackedBar',
  StackedColumn = 'StackedColumn',
  DonutStat = 'DonutStat',
  HalfDonutStat = 'HalfDonutStat',
  ProgressBarStat = 'ProgressBarStat',
  IconStat = 'IconStat',
  Area = 'Area',
  StackedArea = 'StackedArea',
}

type DataTableChartType = typeof ChartType["Pie"]
  | typeof ChartType["DonutPie"]
  | typeof ChartType["Column"]
  | typeof ChartType["Bar"]
  | typeof ChartType["Line"]
  | typeof ChartType["Area"]
  | typeof ChartType["StackedColumn"]
  | typeof ChartType["StackedBar"]


type ChartOptionType = {
  value: DataTableChartType,
  label: string,
  icon: ReactElement,
}

type AvailableChartsType = {
  [key in DataTableChartType]: ChartOptionType;
};

const AVAILABLE_CHARTS: AvailableChartsType = {
  [ChartType["Pie"]]: {
    value: ChartType["Pie"],           //<------------- error here
    label: 'Pie chart',
    icon: <PieChartIcon width='15' />,
  }
}
```

I really don't understand why this is happening. Could you please explain?

`TS2322: Type 'ChartType' is not assignable to type 'DataTableChartType'.`
`ChartWidgetToolbar.tsx(69, 3): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'ChartOptionType'`

If I change the data type to `string` then it works.

Also if I add  `as DataTableChartType`, but I'm wondering why this "cast" is needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why this is a problem, but the issue is this line:

```
[ChartType["Pie"]]: {
```

If you change it to use dot notation instead of bracket notation, the error goes away:

```
[ChartType.Pie]: {
```

(You'll then get another error, which is just pointing out that AVAILABLE_CHARTS needs more than just the pie chart)

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMIAsCGsAqAnmMHAN4BQcc+OARgDakC8cA5LY8GwDRVwAFAJYt2w7n2oARCChji4rNjLnje-DBAZpEi9pu2pE66gCE8etuagm4AGSGJRbB09sBlGDgDGAa2AAJtaWnj7+QXgeXn6BBjoh0eFxRrYqyDCh8EppGV4wtgASOAwAZjmZlkWl5Xm2AlAQAOZQwADOrdYVSvVNLe2dtZJwAJLesl3so+OD-ACCLTiW88A4UWGBy4tKoTEBm+oAvhQUMMSkUjhenEzYeDBEJHqnJBAlmLgEZwDaAETiPwBdfgAHzgz2Ar3edwewF+OX+QOooPBkNunxIv2SiEBILBZ1RH3u3x+1hxSLxLzeaKJGJ+rmAZLgyPxVMJMN+m0ZzMpUPRsJ+OySWh0XIpENZ0OJgsCpKBx3BvJgAHkwDAhLIYXpKNQAG7FZDAABccAuV3oNzZZyGDHowAYxtaMCgjkaQyEY0QxoASitvDAAKJMVBIGB8I4nM5wWZ6oQ2rjU1qa1jauBffyEOCOE2XHDXYDUmEA43UlVqjVnADcFAOVYoHsdYLaWUV7L+IkBtfr8FmADVZsM7LNTHZ-QB9DAFWZe-DuY3RnCx835wmJyPJ-hfAtnAB04iL5H4uv1RpbxIRPGol6v1AA9DeADwAWmfL9fL4QUAaUDgWGALUPcBxnaxpsAo3iErY1DurIxr3uI1JTLoADuQgBDAWDMGwACMACsbBwDeAB8QxHAcQA)

Comment: This looks like a known bug, described at [ms/TS#25083](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25083).  I'd also recommend using dot notation here, noting that this only works when your enum key is a valid identifier.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't explain to myself why this was an issue